# different text style on same line

Tags: html, css, text, alignment, lines

I have 2 styles of text and i am tring to align the first and second one horizontally, on the same line, to be somethig like this:

```
AAA   aaa
BBB   bbb
CCC   ccc
DDD   ddd

EEE   eee
```

but i cannot seem to obtain something close to this, because of the differences in heights between the styles.

This is my code:

```css
div {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div style="float: left; width: 44%; padding: 0 10px 0 0;">
<h2 style="text-align: right;">aaa<br/>
bbb<br/>
ccc<br/>
ddd</h2>
<h2 style="text-align: right;">eee</h2>
</div>
<div style="float: right; width: 52%; padding: 0 10px 0 0;">
<h3>aaa<br/>
bbb<br/>
ccc<br/>
ddd</h3>
<h3>eee</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: and the purpose of this ? .. why aligning things that are not the same ?

Comment: I am tring to create a text table with 2 different styles. It has to be readable so it “should” to be aligned.

Comment: so simply use table

Comment: using tables brings the same problem.

Comment: can you show a screenshot on how you want the alignement, so i can understand well :)

Answer (score 0):

You:"I have 2 styles of text and i am tring to align the first and second one horizontally,"

Instead of using floats on block elements(the divs) you can set the display style of the block elements to inline-block.

IMO, putting the text in an unordered list will improve comprehension. 
You did not list any limitation to what you are trying to accomplish so I just tried to accomplish what you state.

FYI,you should try to keep your styles separate from your HTML as much as possible.

```css
ul{
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  /*h2 is 1.5 em*/
  font-size: 1.5em
}

body ul:nth-child(2){
  /* h3 is 1.3 em */
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

li{
  /*indirectly sets a uniform baseline, the value is arbitrary*/
  height: 40px;    
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>aaa</li>
  <li>bbb</li>
  <li>ccc</li>
  <li>ddd</li>
  <li>eee</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>aaa</li>
  <li>bbb</li>
  <li>ccc</li>
  <li>ddd</li>
  <li>eee</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this helps, but the main differences between the two styles is not just the heigth of the text, but the type of text.

Comment: You will need to provide a better visual example of what the problem is AND all the code containing the  problem.  I'm not sure how to address the other issue.